# reverse dataframe's rows' order with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

How can I reverse the order of the rows in my **pandas.dataframe**?

I've looked everywhere and the only thing people are talking about is sorting the **columns**, reversing the order of the **columns**...

What I want is simple :

If my DataFrame looks like this:

```
   A      B     C
 ------------------
  LOVE    IS   ALL
  THAT   MAT   TERS
```

I want it to become this:

```
   A      B     C
 ------------------
  THAT   MAT   TERS
  LOVE    IS   ALL
```

I know I can iterate over my data in reverse order but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check out http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

You can do

```
reversed_df = df.iloc[::-1]
```